# Any tips for a new grad in power engineering in Australia?

Tags: power, transformer, distribution-network, busbar

I am close to graduating from EE at an Australian university. I've recently found a job in the electrical distribution field and I'm realising that I know close to nothing about the standards and equipment used in the field. Does anyone know any good resources that can be used to help bring a new grad up to speed? Key information that I'm looking for would include things like sizing of distribution boards, busbars, drawing system one-line diagrams etc. To the guys who made the jump from uni into the power field like me, what advice would you guys have on this? Did you get taught this stuff at uni?

Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE but please note that direct shopping questions will result in fairly prompt closure of your question as per [site rules](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Hi @Transistor, thanks for the heads up. I edited my question now. I'm looking for any tips, whether in the form of a book or some other resource.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a general request for help in finding off-site resources.  Stack Exchange sites are only for specific questions which can be meaningfully answered with technical content in the answer box itself; not for open-ended questions which have an unbounded variety of responses, and not for links to material elsewhere (though answers with stand alone technical value may be augmented with *supporting* links)

Comment: Congratulations on almost graduating. We can't really answer this question but I can tell you that since you'll soon be an entry level engineer, companies wouldn't fully expect you to know everything. It wouldn't hurt to ask your professors before you graduate. Talk to them about how you're looking for a job as you get ready to graduate and you have some questions in regards to some of the requirements you've seen online for particular jobs. Your first job will be easier than you think it will be.

Comment: It just goes to show how many different kinds of EE's there are :) And distribution is changing in leaps and bounds as generation moves to solar etc.